# Why won't my Python regular expression anchors work correctly on a multi-line string?

Tags: python, regex, string

I am writing a script to clean up text files which have been converted from PDFs. For some reason, the anchor characters `^` and `$` (matching the beginning and end of the string) do not seem to be working correctly in my regular expressions. I am using Python 3.6.6 on Linux.

Why is `^Credits$` not matching the standalone line `Credits` in the code below?

```
>>> import re
>>> my_regex = r'^Credits$'
>>> my_string = "based upon extrinsic circumstances, as discussed in Serrano v. Priest, 20 Cal.3d 25, 49.\n\nCredits\n(Added by Stats.1977, c. 1197, p. 3979,  1. Amended by Stats.1993, c. 645 (S.B.764),  2.)"
>>> print(re.findall(my_regex,my_string))
[]
```

Here is a snippet of the text (`my_string`) as displayed by the print() function:

```
based upon extrinsic circumstances, as discussed in Serrano v. Priest, 20 Cal.3d 25, 49.

Credits
(Added by Stats.1977, c. 1197, p. 3979,  1. Amended by Stats.1993, c. 645 (S.B.764),  2.)
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: `^` and `$` only match the beginning and end of the string by default. Only with the `m` flag do they also match the beginning and end of lines.

Comment: @CertainPerformance Nice; that worked. So the solution is to use `my_regex = r'(?m)^Credits$'`. I'll accept that answer if you want to post it.

Now I'm confused about the difference is between `^` and `\A` and `$` and `\Z` in Python. I had thought that, given a multi-line string, `^` and `$` would match the beginning and end of lines, while `\A` and `\Z` would match the beginning and end of the entire string.  Are these operators redundant outside of MULTILINE mode?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [@CertainPerformance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52921834/why-wont-my-python-regular-expression-anchors-work-correctly-on-a-multi-line-st#comment92752957_52921834) says, use `re.M` flag at the end of `findall`:

```
print(re.findall(my_regex,my_string,re.M))
```

**Demo:**

```
>>> import re
>>> my_regex = r'^Credits$'
>>> my_string = "based upon extrinsic circumstances, as discussed in Serrano v. Priest, 20 Cal.3d 25, 49.\n\nCredits\n(Added by Stats.1977, c. 1197, p. 3979,  1. Amended by Stats.1993, c. 645 (S.B.764),  2.)"
>>> print(re.findall(my_regex,my_string,re.M))
['Credits']
```

Or Use with `r'(?m)^Credits$'`:

```
>>> import re
>>> my_regex = r'(?m)^Credits$'
>>> my_string = "based upon extrinsic circumstances, as discussed in Serrano v. Priest, 20 Cal.3d 25, 49.\n\nCredits\n(Added by Stats.1977, c. 1197, p. 3979,  1. Amended by Stats.1993, c. 645 (S.B.764),  2.)"
>>> print(re.findall(my_regex,my_string,re.M))
['Credits']
```